# Is This a Valid HeapSort?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, heap

For the past 6 hours, I've been reading tutorials and academic material on constructing a heapsort. I finally have prototyped something in python that sorts a list of integers. However, I'm not entirely sure whether or not my solution constitutes a valid heapsort. It's a very simplistic solution and can definitely be improved upon, but I'm wondering whether it is valid at all. Confusingly, everyone seems to have their own 'preferred' way of implementing this algorithm.

Many thanks in advance.

```
def heapsort(array):
    array = heapify(array)
    array = insert(array, 9999)
    print(array)

def heapify(array):
    end = len(array)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < end:
        while j < end:
            if array[i] > array[j]:
                array = swap(array, i, j)
            j += 1
        i += 1
        j = i
    return array

def insert(array, x):
    array.append(x)
    return heapify(array)


def swap(array, a, b):
    temp = array[a]
    array[a] = array[b]
    array[b] = temp
    return array

def main(array):
    heapsort(array)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    array = [3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 0]
    main(array)
```

Comment: "but I'm wondering whether it is valid at all." - run it with test data! (including in order ascending/descending, random, small sets, large sets) while that won't prove it's correctness it will at least show up any obvious flaws.

Comment: `def swap(array, a, b): array[a], array[b] = array[b], array[a]`

Comment: Note that Python has a `heapq` module you can test against.

Comment: And no, I'm pretty sure this isn't a heap sort - consider the time complexity of your `heapify` (`O(n²)`) vs the expected time complexity (`O(n)`).

Comment: `array = insert(array, 9999)` - what could possibly be the point of that? Also, heapifying an array doesn't sort it.

Comment: [Free pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) - and corresponding overview. The 'heapify' sort shown is really a [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) variation.

Answer (score 2):

Your heapify() should be comparing elements of Parent/Child within the heap (tree structure). Their relative location within the array  is

```
ChildIndex = 2 * Parent Index + [0|1]  # two children per parent
```

in terms of index into the array. That is not evident in your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

What you have written appears to be a [Selection Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

A heap sort arranges the array into a heap (most simply a binary heap) which is a 
structure in which the time to find the smallest element is O(1) and to remove the smallest element is O(log n) and insertion of an element is also O(log n). It then repeatedly takes the smallest element of this to produce the sorted order.

Comment: Bubble sorts compare adjacent elements. This is selecting the smallest element in the unsorted portion of the array. It just happens to be using the final position for that element as temporary storage for the currently found smallest rather than some extra temporary variable.